# What are the best sources for equity quantitative research?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, equities, research

What are the best sources of quantitative finance research in equities?

I will list a couple and note an asterisk if the research is available by request (i.e. non-clients) or online:

1. BAC-Merrill Lynch - Savita Subramanian
2. Deutsche Bank - Yin Luo*
3. Credit Suisse - Pankaj Patel
4. Barclay's - Matthew Rothman
5. HSBC - Ely Klepfish*
6. Goldman Sachs - Quantitative Strategies
7. Neuberger-Berman - [Wai Lee](https://www.nb.com/europe/strategy_quantitative.html)
8. Nomura - Joseph Mezrich

Perhaps there are also more un-conventional sources of quant research besides sell-side wall street:

1. [Hussman Funds](http://www.hussman.net/) - John Hussman*
2. Emanuel Derman's [collection of papers](http://www.ederman.com/new/index.html)

Comment: Should we make this a community wiki?

Comment: Good idea, although I'm not sure how to do do that. Feel free to edit if n'ecy.

Comment: I've converted to community wiki.

Comment: Shouldn't we modify the question so that is doesn't specify the Equity asset class but Quant Finance in general? Or should I create another question?

Comment: @SRXX - The research sources vary by asset class. Only 2 of the folks on the list above cover derivatives for example.

Comment: I would love to revisit this topic and update it for 2016

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Sell Side**

- Macquarie Quant - Venkat Eleswarapu
- Bernstein Research - Vadim Zlotnikov
- Nomura - Joe Mezrich
- JPMorgan Investment Strategies series
- Societe Generale - Alain Bokobza

**Independent**

- [CXO Advisory](http://www.cxoadvisory.com/)
- [Empirical Finance Blog](http://blog.empiricalfinancellc.com/)
- [Russell Indexes: Research and Insights](http://www.russell.com/indexes/tools-resources/research-insights.asp)
- [MSCI Research Papers](http://www.msci.com/resources/research_papers/)
- [Axioma Research Papers](http://www.axiomainc.com/research_papers.htm)

Answer (score 11):

Quantivity's ["People of Quant Research"](http://quantivity.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/people-of-quant-research/)([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528215145/https://quantivity.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/people-of-quant-research/)) has quite an exhaustive list (albeit not exclusively equity-orientated).

Comment: Not a bad list overall, but it seems kind of random and idiosyncratic.  Even though my PhD advisor is on the list, I think there are a number of people there that are not necessarily at the top in terms of practical quant, and also a great many practical quant guys missing.  No offense to quantivity (I enjoy the blog), but the list seems overly driven by whatever has happened to capture quantivity's interest over the years.

Comment: You should add quantivity's twitter feed. I check it every day.

Comment: @John Looks like https://twitter.com/quantivity?lang=en isn't active anymore

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sad. It was a good resource.

Answer (score 7):

definitely add:

- http://www.moneyscience.com/pg/linklibrary/financial-research